# SpringBoot 3 WebFlux - 415 Unsupported MediaType

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm facing a persistent issue in my Spring WebFlux application when trying to handle multipart requests. The specific error message I'm encountering is "Unsupported media type." Despite exploring various solutions suggested on Stack Overflow and GitHub, I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Here's an overview of what I've tried:

Setting Headers:
I attempted to set headers with different values to ensure compatibility, but the issue persists.

Codecs and Header Resolvers:
I experimented with codecs and header resolvers in an attempt to handle media types appropriately, but this did not solve the problem.

Changing File Types:
I switched from MultiPartFile to FilePart to see if it would have any impact on the media type handling, but the error remains.

Body Extraction Methods:
I explored different methods for extracting the body, including using bodyToMono and trying to directly extract multipart values.

Here's the relevant code snippet from the method causing the issue:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> addNewSlide(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
      return serverRequest.bodyToMono(CreateSlideRequest.class)
                .doOnNext(this.validationUtils::validateRequest)
                .flatMap(request -> DataBufferUtils.join(request.imageFile().content())
                        .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                        .flatMap(dataBuffer -> {
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                            String imageName = request.imageFile().filename() + UUID.randomUUID();
                            dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                            Path path = Path.of(uploadDir + "/" + imageName);
                            try {
                                Files.write(path, bytes);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                return Mono.error(new SlideException("Fail to save slide image!"));
                            }
                            return Mono.just(imageName);
                        })
                        .flatMap(imageName -> {
                            Slide slide = slideMapper.slideRequestToSlide(request);
                            slide.setImage(imageName);
                            return slideRepository.save(slide);
                        })
                        .flatMap(ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)::bodyValue));
    }
```

also this is how i crated api router for this method what i have tried:

```
              `POST("api/v1/slides",accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).and(contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))),(sliderHandler::addNewSlide))`
```

This is my class:

```
public record CreateSlideRequest(@NotNull
                                 @Size(min = 10 , max = 100, message = "Min length is 10 char and max 50 chars!")
                                 String buttonTitle,
                                 @NotNull
                                 @Size(min = 10 , max = 100, message = "Min length is 10 char and max 50 chars!")
                                 String title,
                                 @NotNull
                                 @Size(min = 10 , max = 100, message = "Min length is 10  char and max 50 chars!")
                                 String buttonUrl,
                                 @NotNull(message = "Image is required!")
                                 FilePart imageFile) {
}
```

Also i tryed with Normal class, with implement serialiazble, with MultiPartFile

Comment: Can you verify the media type of the incoming request header or at least say more on how you are generated the request?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public Mono<ServerResponse> addSlide(ServerRequest request) {

       return request.body(BodyExtractors.toMultipartData())
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new SlideException("Invalid data")))
                .flatMap(multiValueMap ->
                        multiValueMap.getFirst("createSlideRequest").content().map(dataBuffer -> {
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                            dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                            DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                            return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        })
                        .collectList()
                        .flatMap(strings -> {
                            try {
                                CreateSlideRequest createSlideRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(String.join("", strings), CreateSlideRequest.class);
                                FilePart file = (FilePart) multiValueMap.getFirst("imageFile");

                                createSlideRequest.setImageFile(file);
                                validationUtils.validateRequest(createSlideRequest);
                                String imageName = file.filename().concat(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

                                 file.transferTo(Paths.get(uploadDir).resolve("static/".concat(imageName)))
                                        .doOnSuccess(unused -> System.out.println("Susces"))
                                        .doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println(throwable.getMessage() + " error"))
                                        .subscribe();

                                Slide slide = slideMapper.slideRequestToSlide(createSlideRequest);
                                slide.setEnabled(true);
                                slide.setImage(imageName);

                                return slideRepository.save(slide);
                            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                                return Mono.error(new SlideException("Wrong fields input!"));
                            }
                        }))
               .flatMap(ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)::bodyValue);
    }
```

in the postman i send CreateSlideRequest as a json with content type (application/json)

```
{
  "buttonTitle": "SampleButtonTitle",
  "title": "SampleTitle",
  "buttonUrl": "https://example.com"
}
```

and then i add imageFile as file with contentType(multipart/form-data)